# Flutter / SQFLite adding rows rawInsert

Tags: flutter, sqlite, sqflite

I am working with an existant SQLite database that is copied from assets. Further now everything is alright but when trying to insert some data in the table an error appears:

> DatabaseException(no such table: Parametre (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1])

and this is my :

```
Future<bool> insertUser (String user, String depot, String pwd) async {
    int result = 0;
    Database database = await openDatabase(dbPath);
    final db = await database;
    try {
      result = await db.rawInsert(
          'INSERT INTO Parametre (USER, DEPOT) VALUES ("$user", "$depot")');
    }catch(e){
      print(e);
    }
    if(result>0){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  }
```

what have i missed?

Comment: The database probably doesn't have a table named "Parametre".

Comment: The table "Parametre" does exist and it is correctly spelled. The problem is shown with all the tables in that database.
when running the app android studio let you see the files on your device. I can see the database and all the tables inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, the problem appeared to be in the dbPath. The dbPath was set to 'assets/myDatabase.db'. First step was to copy the database from the assets to the app.
Second after copying the database i don't have to use the full path to `openDatabase`. The right way was to use only the database name, means `openDatabase('myDatabase.db')`.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, either you've mispelled the table name `Parametre` or you don't have a table with that name in your database. You should run a `CREATE TABLE` statement to create the table somewhere before (or, if you have it in your code, it has not been run or contains some other error).

It may help you knowing that `sqflite` provides two great arguments to its `openDatabase` method: `onCreate` and `onUpdate`. They allow you to call a custom function when the database is created (a simple way to create all the tables your app needs at the first run) and another different function to update your database by adding tables or altering columns if you just provide a coherent `version` argument to the same `openDatabase` function.

Comment: The table "Parametre" does exist and it is correctly spelled. The problem is shown with all the tables in that database. when running the app android studio let you see the files on your device. I can see the database and all the tables inside it.
In my case i work with an existing database and i should not create any new table inside it. I tried to create an android java project and copying and accessing the table works like charm but i have found issues with flutter.

Comment: The `dbPath` used in the `openDatabase` is correct?

Comment: As a first step, you can check the list of existing tables of your database using `print(await db.query("sqlite_master"));`, to make sure that you are indeed using the same database that you see in android studio and as suggested above bump the version number and use onCreate/onUpdate to modify the overall schema.